# Dynamic/responsive CSS sizing

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a map with location markers and I want to change the size of the markers when a user zooms in/out. I'm capturing the zoom level in state and it's a floating point number (i.e. 11.3235).

How can I pass this number (from state) to a css class so the size of my markers would dynamically change its size? Instead of having a small/medium/large marker, I want the width and height of my marker to be precise according to the zoom level.

```
class Mapbox extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      viewport: {
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        latitude: 49.2463,
        longitude: -123.1162,
        zoom: 11
      },
      active_vehicles: [],
      marker_size: 0,
    };
  }

  _onViewportChange = viewport => {
    this.setState({viewport});

  // Depending on zoom level, change Markers' class to dynamically change their display size/style
    this.setState({marker_size: this.state.viewport.zoom})

  };

  createMarkers = () => {
    let markers = []

    if(this.state.active_vehicles){
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.active_vehicles.length; i++) {
        markers.push(
        <Marker key={i} latitude={this.state.active_vehicles[i]["Latitude"]} longitude={this.state.active_vehicles[i]["Longitude"]}>
          <div className={"location-marker " + this.state.marker_size}></div>
        </Marker>
        )
      }
      return markers
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactMapGL
        // mapbox API access token
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
        {...this.state.viewport}
        onViewportChange={this._onViewportChange}>

        <div>
          {this.createMarkers()}
        </div>

      </ReactMapGL>
    );
  }   
}
```

Comment: I don’t think you can pass state to css. But what you can do is, use inline style. Create a style object in render function and based on your zoom state value calculate markers size. You can check in react documentation about inline style. This should do the trick

Comment: Are your markers in svg? Web font? What does `.location-marker` display?